# How to submit XML String to Server via WebService

Tags: android, web-services, android-ksoap2

I want to submit the following xml String to server via webservce in android device.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<submit>
 <work pk_sysuser="u0001" pk_work="work0001">
  <captaincompany>abc</captaincompany>
   <task_list>
    <task itemcode="t0001">2</task>
     <task itemcode="t0002">2013-12-31 12:00:00</task>
     <task itemcode="t0003">2013-12-31 13:00:00</task>
     <task itemcode="t0004">2</task>
     <task itemcode="t0005">Y</task>
     </task_list>
     <signaturepath>pic string</signaturepath>
 </work>
</submit>
```

If I create the soapobject as following:
soapobject.addproperty("workdata", xmlString);

and send it to server that would result in java.io.eofexception.
Can anyone help me out?